# Passing parameters to a static front page

Tags: query, variables, parameter

I have googled a lot, but so far haven't come close to a proper solution yet. I need help with passing parameters to the homepage of a WordPress website. Here's my setup / requirements:

1. I use a page template (say, MCTemplate) that is set as the static front page in Settings -> Reading.
2. I use 'Post name' permalink structure.
3. I need to pass a single parameter (say, mcdata) to the static homepage (i.e., MCTemplate).

I have used the following code in functions.php, but when I pass the parameter to the homepage (e.g., http://www.example.com/?mcdata=helloword), it show a list of latest posts instead of static front page.

```
function mc_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'mcdata';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'mc_query_vars' );
```

Using front-page.php comes close to solving this, but in that case I cannot use a static front page. Are there any rewrite rules or anything that I should change to get it working with the above requirements? All help is appreciated.

Comment: I removed the comment and create an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`front-page.php` **is** a static front page (if you rename your current template `front-page.php`, and don't select nothing in *Settings->Reading* it works exactly like now.

However, if you want to use the *page* approach and you **don't** use `mcdata` for query, remove the filter you posted, and simply retrieve the `mcdata` value in your template using `$_GET['mcdata'];`.

Comment: The confusion was due to two queries: the WordPress loop query (WP_Query) and the URL query string. Thanks for the quick clarification.

Comment: Knowing that the site front page was a 'static' page, and then finding this, was the solution for me too. Trying to set a 'query_vars' hook for the query parameters I wanted to look at disrupts existing code using is_front_page(), and prevented the static front page from displaying.

Answer (score 0):

To pass parameter on the front page static I use the prefix "ch_" as follow:

http://www.example.com/?ch_mcdata=helloword

in this way it will work.

Comment: What is the significance of the `ch_` prefix?

Comment: nothing to do specifically with ch_ its because the query_var isn't registered with ch_ in front so WordPress doesn't try and process it.

You could use any characters before it to get it to work.